# class extension in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am learning object-c by reading a book. When I read the chapter about class extension, the book gives the following example code:

```
// A class extension
@interface BNREmployee ()

@property (nonatomic) unsigned int officeAlarmCode;

@end

@implementation BNREmployee
...
@end
```

The book says **objects that are not instances of `BNREmployee` can no longer see this property** `officeAlarmCode`. It makes an example:

```
BNREmployee *mikey = [[BNREmployee alloc] init];
unsigned int mikeysCode = mikey.officeAlarmCode;
```

This attempt would result in a compiler error that reads “No visible @interface declares the instance method officeAlarmCode”.

But I get confused. I mean I feel the book's words & its example code are contradictory. Book says objects that are not instance of `BNREmployee` can not longer see property `officeAlarmCode`. But in the example code above, isn't `mikey` an instance of `BNREmployee`? Why it cannot see `officeAlarmCode` event it is an instance of `BNREmployee` ?

**=== UPDATE =====**

The book I am reading is [this one](http://www.bignerdranch.com/we-write/objective-c-programming.html). Chapter 22, page 162.

I just want to verify that the book explained in a misleading way & I am looking for a clear explanation here. Because book says "objects that are **NOT** instance of `BNREmployee` can no longer see property officeAlarmCode", for the book reader like me, I feel it hints objects that are instance of `BNREmployee` CAN SEE property `officeAlarmCode`. That's why I am confusing, because `mikey` is an instance of `BNREmployee` but it can't access officeAlarmCode.

Comment: What means is that the compiler, when compiling other modules, "cannot see" the extensions (for the simple reason that the definitions are not included via the `#import` of the corresponding .h file).  Has nothing to do with whether the methods can actually be called from elsewhere (they can).

Comment: `mikey` can access the property just fine but, in the sample code, it's a different object attempting to **use** `mikey` to get external access.

Comment: @PhillipMills , what do you mean "mikey can access the property just fine" ? e.g. mikey.officeAlarmCode; is not fine. Can you expand your words more?

Comment: `mikey.officeAlarmCode` is not a case of a `BNREmployee` accessing the property.  It is a case of some other code trying to get the property by using `mikey.` as a path.  If a method existed inside  `BNREmployee` that wanted to use the property through `self` that would be access by the owner and would work.  (Imagine that you ask me for my bank account and I refuse to give it to you.  I can still access it just fine even though "Phillip.account" isn't available to you.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) 
1. a class extension can add its own properties and instance variables to a class
2. Class extensions are often used to extend the public interface with additional private methods or properties for use within the implementation of the class itself.

so if you declare the property in class extension it will be visible only to the implementation file. like

in `BNREmployee.m`

```
@interface BNREmployee ()

@property (nonatomic) unsigned int officeAlarmCode;

@end

@implementation BNREmployee

- (void) someMethod {
    //officeAlarmCode will be available inside implementation block to use
     _officeAlarmCode = 10;
}
@end
```

If you want to use officeAlarmCode in other classes, let's say OtherEmployee class then you need to create officeAlarmCode property in BNREmployee.h file with readOnly or readWrite access. Then you can use it like

```
BNREmployee.h

@property (nonatomic, readOnly) unsigned int officeAlarmCode; //readOnly you can just read not write
```

in `OtherEmployee.m`

```
import "BNREmployee.h"
@interface OtherEmployee ()

@property (nonatomic) unsigned int otherAlarmCode;

@end

@implementation OtherEmployee
```

you can create instance of `BNREmployee` and can assign `officeAlarmCode` value to `otherAlarmCode` property like below

```
BNREmployee *bnrEmployee = [BNREmployee alloc] init];
_otherAlarmCode = bnrEmployee.officeAlarmCode;
```

Comment: This is the most clear explanation for me, thanks. But @A-live 's example is also interesting, a class implementation could also access properties in class extension of another class, if they are defined in the same file ?

Comment: Yes it's possible to access the properties of Collection classes(Like NSString or NSArray etc) in implementation file. Plus if you want to access properties of other classes which user has created then you need to can access those if you keep those properties in .h file when you create that class.

Comment: I would suggest you to refer the apple docs link I mentioned above, it has the best explanation possible for basic building blocks for Objective-C

Answer (score 4):

Mikes is an instance of BNREmployee.  But the example is telling you that the property `officeAlarmCode` is not exposed and can only be used by BNREmployee objects internally.

Comment: Book says "objects that are not instance of BNREmployee can not longer see property officeAlarmCode", for the book reader like me, I feel it hints objects that are instance of BNREmployee can see property officeAlarmCode. That's why I am confusing, because mikey is an instance of BNREmployee but it can't access officeAlarmCode.

Comment: @Leem.fin Please give the name of the book so I don't buy it.

Comment: @Abizern, what do you mean "can only be used by BNREmployee objects" ? What is the definition of BNREmployee objects? Do you mean BNREmployee class ?

Comment: An object is an instance of a class.  When you call alloc and init on a class you are creating an instance, a concrete object of that class.

Answer (score 2):

It is a little bit misleading to say "objects can no longer see". Objects doesn't see anything, even in the figurative sense. Let`s say: *Code* placed outside the implementation of the class cannot see the property.

Answer (score 1):

```
BNREmployee *mikey = [[BNREmployee alloc] init];
unsigned int mikeysCode = mikey.officeAlarmCode;
```

- This code is in a file. That file (and that class) isn't BNREmployee.m .This code is in a non-BNREmployee object. Lets call the object in which this code exists *foo* .
- mikey is a BNREmployee object.
- This code tries to access the officeAlarmCode property of a BNREmployee object.
- When foo wants to use a BNREmployee object (like mikey), the properties it can access are only the ones in BNREmployee.h.
- As officeAlarmCode doesn't exist in BNREmployee.h, foo cannot access the officeAlarmCode property of mikey, because this property isn't in the interface ( BNREmployee.h file).
- As mikey is a BNREmployee object, it can see the officeAlarmCode, and use it.
- Where is mikey's code which can use the officeAlarmCode? mikey's code is in BNREmployee.m file. So the only code that can use the officeAlarmCode is the implementation of BNREmployee.

Comment: Your explanation is illuminating. I had the same confusion as the poster. Given other programming books I've read , I must say this book is for sure unclear and misleading about this concept.

Answer (score 0):

Think contexts, any other class can access the properties declared at the extensions or any categories as far as the extended interfaces are "visible" at the given context.

For example, the following implementation file contains implementation of two interfaces: `BaseObject` and `BaseObjectController`. At the implementation of the other class (`BaseObjectController`) you can safely use the "hidden" property via getters and setters because the declaration interface is "visible". If you move the implementation of `BaseObjectController` to another file that can't see declaration of the extension - this code won't compile.

```
#import "BaseObject.h"
#import "BaseObjectController.h"

//  BaseObject    
@interface BaseObject()
@property (strong) NSString * idString;
@end

@implementation BaseObject
@end

//  BaseObjectController    
@implementation BaseObjectController
- (void) initBaseObject {
    BaseObject * bo = [BaseObject new];
    bo.idString = @"01234";
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

What I got from it is that the property `officeAlarmCode` is only visible within the `BNREmployee.m` file, it will not be accessible from `main.m`.

To pass the value to `mikeysCode` you would have to create a method that returns `officeAlarmCode`.